# Windows 10 Home - Who is starting a process at logon?

Tags: windows-10, boot, login, logging, process-monitor

Whenever I login into Windows 10 Home, a cmd screen starts with a batch file inside `windows\system32`. Antivirus shows nothing, SysInternals autoruns shows no call to `cmd.exe` or to the batch file.

Using Process Explorer, the parent of cmd.exe is "Non-existent Process", but the cmd.exe is below winlogon.exe in the tree-view, which makes me suspicious of some entry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

However, there are countless entries there and I'm afraid of breaking something if I disable everything. The batch itself is harmless - it only logs current date and time at a text file then pauses. I've used Process Monitor and never see any process accessing that file in my normal use.

Since this happens at login time, it's too late for me using Process Monitor. Since this is Windows 10 Home, I can't enable process audit logs.

Is there some tool I can download to find out who is starting that `cmd.exe` and/or batch file? Or how can I prepare Process Monitor to run before everything else at logon?

Comment: What DOES Autoruns show?

Comment: Few other things to check: the `/startup` folder, Task Scheduler (show hidden tasks) and look for processes that trigger at logon, and check `services.msc` for anything suspicious. Also note, that there could be login within an exe that executes a batch or creates a batch dynamically, execute it, and then deletes the batch. Run a full anti-malware scan as well.

Comment: [use WPRUI to log boot process and analyze the boot with WPA.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1203180/174557), here you can see all programs that are started during boot.